# Utility to show Windows domain controller reachability?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Is there a utility that presents a tray icon showing domain controller reachability?

I have a laptop PC joined to a corp domain, and I roam sometimes, losing Wifi connectivity to my corp LAN. So I'd like to have a small utility that can notify me when the DC becomes reachable or unreachable, so that I can know in advance whether some Active Directory related operation is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the network icon in the system tray. It will show you the names of the networks that you're connected to.